# cat multiple files based on ID in filename

Tags: bash, cat

I would like to combine files with similar ID before first underscore into one file using `cat`. How do I do this for multiple files like below?
Thought of something like this:

```
for f in *.R1.fastq.gz; do cat "$f" > "${f%}.fastq.gz"; done
```

in

```
9989_L004_R1.fastq.gz
9989_L005_R1.fastq.gz
9989_L009_R1.fastq.gz
9873_L008_R1.fastq.gz
9873_L005_R1.fastq.gz
9873_L001_R1.fastq.gz
```

out

```
9989.fastq.gz
9873.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623710

Answer (score 3):

```
for f in *_R1.fastq.gz; do cat "$f" >> "${f%%_*}.fastq.gz"; done
```

- `>>` for appending,
- `${f%%_*}` removes the longest suffix in `$f` matching `_*`.

Comment: Does this keep the original files as well?

Comment: I guess it should be. *_R1.fastq.gz  instead of    *.R1.fastq.gz

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
for f in *_R1.fast1.gz; do 
   [[ -f "${f%%_*}.fastq.gz" ]] || cat ${f%%_*}_*_R1.fast1.gz > "${f%%_*}.fastq.gz"
done
```

or if  you want to have it a bit more readable:

```
for f in *_R1.fast1.gz; do 
   key="${f%%_*}"
   [[ -f "${key}.fastq.gz" ]] || cat ${key}_*_R1.fast1.gz > "${key}.fastq.gz"
done
```