# Concatenate multiple files based on similar ID in a loop

Tags: bash, loops, concatenation, cat, parameter-expansion

I have these files in the same folder:

```
results1_1_2_4
results2_1_2_4
results3_1_2_4
results4_1_2_4
results5_1_2_4

results1_0.001_2_25
results2_0.001_2_25
results3_0.001_2_25
results4_0.001_2_25
results5_0.001_2_25

results1_0.1_3_50
results2_0.1_3_50
results3_0.1_3_50
results4_0.1_3_50
results5_0.1_3_50
```

I would like to combine the five files `results1+results2+results3+results4+results5` for each combination, for example "1_2_4", "0.001_2_25" and "0.1_3_50". So the ouput should be:

```
results_1_2_4
results_0.001_2_25
results_0.1_3_50
```

A similar question is here ([cat multiple files based on ID in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650034/cat-multiple-files-based-on-id-in-filename)), but I tried with no success:

```
for f in results*; do cat "$f" >> "results${*_f%%}"; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a slight adjustment to the parameter expansion:

```
for f in results*; do
  cat "$f" >> "results_${f#*_}"
done
```